# How to code a Fortran function that return an array

Tags: fortran

In my study i have to code 4 matrix, so i code this but i have a error that i don't understand.

my function:

```
function matrix(x_axis,Nblines) result(m)
    implicit none
    real(kind=8),dimension(3,3) :: m
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: x_axis(Nblines)
    integer :: i, j


    do i=1,3
        do j=1,3
            m(i,j) = sum(x_axis**(int(i+j-2)))/Nblines
            
        end do 
    end do 
end function matrix
```

x_axis is a vector and i compute multiple average on it.
I have this error:

```
Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)
```

I read someone on same type of error and this solution is about interfaces but i don't understand this.

Comment: We need to see all of the error message, especially where that `(1)` is pointing. You haven't given `nblines` a type so either that's not the code you're compiling, or you have another error relating to that.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and see [ask]. We really need more details. Alwsys show the complete error message. Read [mcve] to see how to prepare en example for a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question you asked, even though it's not likely to be your ultimate issue.

For the diagnostic (which is NOT an error): Somewhere, in code you have not shown us, you have an array reference such as `a(x)` where `x` is REAL type and not INTEGER. This is not allowed nowadays in Fortran but was, decades ago, and many compilers still support it as an extension. The compiler is doing you a favor and pointing it out. It's bad practice and probably an error on your part.

Regarding functions returning arrays, this requires that an "explicit interface" be visible to the caller. The best way to do this is to put your function in a `module` and `use` the module from where you want to call it. I discussed explicit interfaces in more detail at https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2012/01/05/doctor-fortran-gets-explicit-again/

Comment: sorry my program for the first post was with many dum mistakes... Now i just try to bluid a function that take in argument 2 vectors and i want return a array with the average on this vector for the elements of the array but i have to build an interface i think and i don't understand this, i have try modules but this is not working...

Comment: You don't have to "build an interface" - either create a module and place the function in it, or use CONTAINS in your main program and have the function after that. Both of these create the required interface. More than that I can't say since you don't show your code and don't say what "not working" means.  See Vladimir F's reply to your initial question.